# Most idiomatic way to parse a list with a hole in the middle, in F#

Tags: f#

I am parsing an excel file which is organized that way:

```
header1
header2
data
data
[...]
data
one blank line
data
data
[...]
data
one blank line
```

So, we have a header, to skip, some data of variable length, a blank line, some data of variable length and a blank line to mark the end of the zone of interest.

The two data chunks are parsed in an identical way and they have to end up in a single list, but what is important is that I know the index of the blank line in the middle (it's a list that gets processed from the middle, either toward the top, or toward the bottom).

There are two caveats:

- The top and bottom parts don't have the same length.
- One of the sides can be empty.

Right now, I have an implementation that's not very clean since it duplicates code:

```
let gridRowsUp =
    gridExcel
    |> List.skip 2
    |> List.takeWhile (fun rowData       -> rowData |> Seq.exists(fun x -> not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(x))))
    |> List.mapi      (fun index rowData -> parseGridLayer (index + 2) rowData)

// get the index of the middle row
let middleRow = 2 + gridRowsUp.Length

// get the bottom part of the grid
let gridRowsDown =
    gridExcel
    |> List.skip      (1 + middleRow)
    |> List.takeWhile (fun rowData       -> rowData |> Seq.exists(fun x -> not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(x))))
    |> List.mapi      (fun index rowData -> parseGridLayer (index + 1 + middleRow) rowData)

let gridData = gridRowsUp @ gridRowsDown
```

Ideally, I'd like to process the data lines in one go but skip and record the location of, the blank line in the middle.

I thought about finding the first blank line and rebuild a list without it (since I now know the index), but it's convoluted since I need to find the first one, then find the second one to know where to stop (there can be a lot of unused extra lines below) then build one list again. And removing an element in the middle of a list in F# is not ideal.

How can I make this more streamlined?

Answer (score 1):

I thought a loop would be better than repeating code. This code should clarify the logic.

```
// main dataset
let gridExcel = [
"header1";  "header2";   "data1";    "data2";    "data3";    "data4";    "";
"data5";    "data6";     "";
"data7";    "data8";     "data9";    "data10";    "";
"data11";   "data12";    "data13";   "data14";   "data15";    "";
"data16";   "data17"
]

let mutable blanks = []  // index of blank lines
let mutable allrows = []  // all non-blanks rows (no headers)

let mutable ctr = 2  // row index of main data
let mutable run = true

while (run) do
   let gridRows = 
       gridExcel
       |> List.skip ctr  // skip previous data
       |> List.takeWhile (fun rowData       -> not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(rowData)))  // while not empty line
       |> List.mapi      (fun index rowData -> "xx" + rowData)   // process entry
   allrows <- allrows@gridRows    // add to list total
   ctr <- ctr + gridRows.Length   // add to skip ctr
   if (ctr < gridExcel.Length) then blanks <- blanks@[ctr]   // store blank line index
   ctr <- ctr + 1  // skip blank line
   if (ctr >= gridExcel.Length) then run <- false  // done main list
   
printfn "Blanks: %A\n" blanks   // indexes of blanks lines
printfn "Processed Data:\n%A" allrows  // all processed rows
```

Output

```
Blanks: [6; 9; 14; 20]

Processed Data:
["xxdata1"; "xxdata2"; "xxdata3"; "xxdata4"; "xxdata5"; "xxdata6"; "xxdata7";
 "xxdata8"; "xxdata9"; "xxdata10"; "xxdata11"; "xxdata12"; "xxdata13";
 "xxdata14"; "xxdata15"; "xxdata16"; "xxdata17"]
```

Comment: the end of the data is the second blank line,  but yes, it could be adapted easily. In the end, this doesn't simplify the code since the version posted could have duplication removed easily. What I was hoping for is something that would allow to record / skip the first white line while processing everything in one go

Answer (score 1):

Using @mike67 testdata. Maybe something like this?

```
    let gridExcel = [
    "header1";  "header2";   "data1";    "data2";    "data3";    "data4";    "";
    "data5";    "data6";     "";
    "data7";    "data8";     "data9";    "data10";    "";
    "data11";   "data12";    "data13";   "data14";   "data15";    "";
    "data16";   "data17"
    ]

let (|IsNullOrEmpty|Data|) cell = 
    if String.IsNullOrEmpty cell
    then IsNullOrEmpty 
    else Data

let parseRow rCell = "P" + rCell    

let rec parseOrIndexEmpty currentIndex emptyIndexes processed grid = 
    match grid with
    | [] -> (List.rev processed, List.rev emptyIndexes) 
    | row::rows -> 
        match row with 
        //parse Row and continue
        | Data -> 
            parseOrIndexEmpty (currentIndex + 1) emptyIndexes ((parseRow row)::processed) rows 
        //Collect index and continue if it's not beyond second blank line
        | IsNullOrEmpty -> 
            let currentEmptyIndexes = (currentIndex::emptyIndexes)
            if currentEmptyIndexes.Length < 2
            then parseOrIndexEmpty (currentIndex + 1) currentEmptyIndexes processed rows 
            else (List.rev processed, List.rev currentEmptyIndexes)

let numOfHeaders = 2 
let (processed,emptyIndexes) =    
    gridExcel 
    |> List.skip numOfHeaders 
    |> parseOrIndexEmpty numOfHeaders List.empty List.empty

printfn "MiddleRow Index: %d" emptyIndexes.[0]


printfn "Processsed:\n%A" processed

Output:           

MiddleRow Index: 6
Processsed:
["Pdata1"; "Pdata2"; "Pdata3"; "Pdata4"; "Pdata5"; "Pdata6"]
```

If you do not need the index it can be simplified alot.

Answer (score 0):

What about a recursive function like:

```
let parseGridLayer index rowData = sprintf "%d: %s" index rowData    
let isValidRow row = not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row))

let extractData excelData = 
    let rec extracter index data result blankCount = 
        match blankCount with
        | 2 -> result 
        | _ ->
            match data with
            | [] -> result
            | row::remaingRows ->
                match isValidRow row with
                | true -> extracter (index + 1) remaingRows ((parseGridLayer index row)::result) blankCount
                | false -> extracter (index + 1) remaingRows result (blankCount + 1)

    extracter 2 (excelData |> List.skip 2) [] 0 |> List.rev


let gridExcel = [ 
    "header1";  "header2";   "data1";    "data2";    "data3";    "data4"; 
    "data5";    "data6"; 
    "data7";    "data8";     "data9";    "data10";    
    "";
    "data11";   "data12";    "data13";   "data14";   "data15";  
    "data16";   "data17"; 
    ""
]
printfn "%A" (extractData gridExcel)
```